# Don't destroy an Angular Bootstrap modal on close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap to display a Modal (the one presented [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)), which works perfectly. However, default behavior of this Angular extension is that the modal is reconstructed (and a new instance of its controller will be creatred) whenever it is closed and then opened again.

Since I have some pretty advanced stuff going on inside the Modal, I would like the modal to just be hidden when it is closed, so that its state remains. I have searched around a bit, but unfortunately could not find a simple and effective answer.

Just hiding it would be an option, but this then has to happen whenever the modal is closed, so also when it closes because the backdrop is clicked. And I want the same animation as when the modal is opened in the normal way.

Comment: how you close model popup, can you paste code here??

Comment: I open the modal with the $modal.open() function and it is closed by e.g. clicking on the backdrop. I did not have to provide any code for that, I just do a $modal.open() every time a user clicks on a link that opens the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you abstract the modal state into its own service? That way, whenever the modal controller is created, it uses the service to setup the view state on initialisation.

Eg. create a service

```
.factory('ModalStateService', function(){
    var state = {
        someValue: 'something'
    };

    return {
        getState: function() { return state; }
    };
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, ModalStateService){
    $scope.viewState = ModalStateService.getState();
});
```

Then in your modal content view for example:

```
<span>{{viewState.someValue}}</span>
```

If you were then to set `someValue` inside your modal, say through an input, the service state would be updated. Then when you create and destroy your modal, the state will persist.

Comment: +1 for the idea, I already thought of something like this, only I just stored state in the parent scope. This idea is better than storing in parent scope. Still, a problem with this approach for me is that I then also have to store things like on which subpage a user is in the modal, what values of unsubmitted forms are etc, while a show/hide action of the modal would allow me to not bother about those things.

Comment: Showing/hiding is fine if it works for you, but it sounds like you are doing something quite complex that possibly shouldn't be in a modal at all. Either way it is good practice to decouple your state from your view.

Comment: I am doing something quite complex, but I wouldn't know why that would mean it shouldn't be in a modal. Even though it is complex, the user should simply be able to get back to what he/she was doing when he/she closes the modal. Anyway, I accepted your answer as the best one for me, and I will just go with remembering the state for now. Thanks again for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know Angular initializes a controller when the associated view is added to the DOM. So the plugin author might have decided to add and remove the view element so that he does not have to worry about clearing the 'scope'each time user opens and closes the modal.

For example, we have a login box in the modal and if the scope is not cleared, it will keep the filled in details even the next time we show it.

An easy hack to solve your problem will be to wrap the originl modal in a custom directive, reneder it. And just change the display property of your custom modal to show and hide the modal ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but could you elaborate somewhat more on the hack you described? How is putting the modal into a directive going to do what I want?