# Hide Angular Bootstrap modal instead of close

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap Modal to open a bunch of modals including video player inside

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

I want to be able to keep where the video is at even if the modal is closed. It's just so next time I open the same modal again, I can see where I left off in the video.

In order to do that, I need to do:

1. Create each modal a separate instance
2. Instead of close(), I need to hide() the modal instead. Therefore the DOMs are still in there and the video player don't get re-created

What's the elegant way to do this as the Bootstrap modal has no hide feature. Should I just use jQuery to show/hide the `.modal-backdrop` and `.modal` classes?

Comment: If it's html5 video, you should have access to the time elapsed (video.currentTime), store that in a variable on close, then on open load the player with that variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't destroy an Angular Bootstrap modal on close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653888/dont-destroy-an-angular-bootstrap-modal-on-close)

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall No it's not html5 video but brightcove.com where they don't have load API at currentTime.

Comment: @KyleMit This question is simplier as I have no state to maintain. It's just the DOM must be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

From [Don't destroy an Angular Bootstrap modal on close](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24653888/1366033):

> Why don't you abstract the modal state into its own service? That way, whenever the modal controller is created, it uses the service to setup the view state on initialisation.
>
> Eg. create a service

```
.factory('ModalStateService', function(){
    var state = {
        someValue: 'something'
    };

    return {
        getState: function() { return state; }
    };
});
```

> Then in your controller:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, ModalStateService){
    $scope.viewState = ModalStateService.getState();
});
```

> Then in your modal content view for example:

```
 <span>{{viewState.someValue}}</span>
```

> If you were then to set `someValue` inside your modal, say through an input, the service state would be updated. Then when you create and destroy your modal, the state will persist.

Comment: I am still vague on `<span>{{viewState.someValue}}</span>`. So how exactly do I hide or show the modal?